# The usage of a backslash character(\) in an char assignment expression

Tags: c, char, escaping, octal

```
char C = '\1'
int I = -3
printf("%d", I * C);
```

output:

```
-3
```

Hi, I just saw this weird syntax in my practice book, but it doesn't give me much detail about what it is and its usage. Why is there a backslash next to `1` in the quotation mark? Is `'\1'` any different from `'1'`? If so, why the result of `I * C` is the same as 1 * 3? Thank you

Comment: ``\`` is for escaping special chars. Like newline (`\n`). See [table of escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences) - `\1` is an octal `1` byte. `printf("%d\n", '\1');` and `printf("%d\n", '1');` give `1` and `49` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The `'1'` is the character “1”. Most platforms nowadays use [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) to translate characters into bytes — `'1'` in ASCII is an integer `49` in decimal or `0x31` in hex.

From [cppreference escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape):

> ```
> \nnn  arbitrary octal value   byte nnn
> ```
>
> Octal escape sequences have a limit of three octal digits, but terminate at the first character that is not a valid octal digit if encountered sooner.

The `'\1'` is an integer `0x1` in hex or `1` in decimal. In ASCII, it is a `SOH` character — start of heading.

The:

```
char C = '\1';
```

is equivalent to:

```
char C = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the initializer of the variable `C`

```
char C = '\1';
```

there is used an octal escape sequence. That is the digits after the backslash are considered as an octal representation of a number.

The number of digits in the octal escape sequence shall not be greater than 3 and the allowed digits are 0-7 inclusively.

For example this declaration

```
char C = '\11';
```

initializes the variable `C` with the value `9`.

So the expression used in the call of `printf`

```
printf("%d", I * C);
```

is equivalent to

```
printf("%d", -3 * 1);
```

And the output will be `-3`.

Instead of the octal escape sequence you could use hexadecimal escape sequence like

```
char C = '\x1';
```

this declaration is equivalent to the previous declaration of the variable `C` like

```
char C = '\1';
```

If to initialize the variable like

```
char C = '\x11';
```

then the variable `C` will get the value `17`.

The number of digits in the octal escape sequence shall not be greater than 3 and the allowed digits are 0-7 inclusively.

As for a declaration like this

```
char C = '1';
```

then the variable `C` is initialized by the value of the internal representation of the character `'1'`. For example if the ASCII coding is used the variable `C` is initialized by the value `49`. If the EBCDIC coding is used then the variable `C` is initialized by the value `241`.

Answer (score 0):

`'1'` is internally a byte whose value is 49 (the ASCII code of symbol 1).
`'\1'` is a byte whose value is 1.